# How do I use tkinter to write into a txt document

Tags: python, windows, list, user-input, thonny

we have a lot of code so far but we can't find anything to record info and send it to a txt document in a reciept style with all the categories. if there is a solution, we can't find it
Here is a snippet of our code

```
#second window - rory
def new1():
 root = Tk( )
 root.config(bg=("#967117"))
 root.geometry( '1100x600+100+100') #where the box will be on the screen
 root.title("CheckOut")
 root.resizable (width=False, height=False)

 # address - rory
 Label (root, text = "Address:").place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.5)
 Label (root, text = "City:").place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.3)
 Label (root, text = "Province/Territory:").place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.1)
 Label (root, text = "Postal Code:").place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.7)
 Label (root, text = "Phone Number:").place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.9)
 depot7 = StringVar()
 depot7.set(None)
 OptionMenu (root, depot7, "British Columbia", "Alberta", "Saskatchewan", "Manitoba","Ontario","Yukon","Northwest Territories","Nunavut","Prince Edward Island","New Brunswick","Quebec","Nova Scotia","Newfoundland and Labrador").place(relx = 0.41 , rely = 0.09)
 address1 = Entry(root, width = 30).place(relx = 0.34 , rely = 0.3)
 address2 = Entry(root, width = 30).place(relx = 0.36 , rely = 0.5)
 address3 = Entry(root, width = 14).place(relx = 0.38 , rely = 0.7)
 pn = Entry(root, width = 18).place(relx = 0.39 , rely = 0.9)

 #payment - rory
 depot11 = StringVar()
 depot11.set(None)
 Label (root, text = "Type of Payment:").place(relx = 0.65 , rely = 0.1)
 OptionMenu (root, depot11, "VISA", "MASTERCARD", "AMERICAN EXPRESS", "DISCOVER").place(relx = 0.75 , rely = 0.09)
 Label (root, text = "Name On Card:").place(relx = 0.65 , rely = 0.3)
 Label (root, text = "Card Number:").place(relx = 0.65 , rely = 0.5)
 Label (root, text = "Expire Date (MM/YY):").place(relx = 0.65 , rely = 0.7)
 Label (root, text = "CVV:").place(relx = 0.65 , rely = 0.9)
 pay1 = Entry(root, width = 30).place(relx = 0.74 , rely = 0.3)
 pay2 = Entry(root, width = 30).place(relx = 0.73 , rely = 0.5)
 pay3 = Entry(root, width = 6).place(relx = 0.77 , rely = 0.7)
 pay4 = Entry(root, width = 6).place(relx = 0.69 , rely = 0.9)
 title = Label(root, text = "Cart", font = 40).place(relx = 0.14 , rely = 0.06)
 cart1 = tk.Text(root, width = 30, height = 28, state='disabled').place(relx = 0.05, rely = 0.1)
def dad():

 fileD = open("qqqq.txt", "a")
 fileD.write("Address:\n")
 fileD.write("%s\n" % address1.get())
 fileD.write("City:\n")
 fileD.write("%s\n" % address2.get())
 fileD.write("Province/Territory:\n")
 fileD.write("%s\n" % address3.get())
 fileD.write("Postal Code:\n")
 fileD.write("%s\n" % pn.get())

 Button(root, bg ="hot pink", text = "Add To Cart", font = 80, borderwidth = 10, relief= "ridge", command = dad).place(relx = 0.2 , rely = 0.2)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn python file operation. I will recommend you to visit this website for a clear understanding.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-python/amp/

Comment: Do you think I could use .get for this as well?

Comment: Did not understand the question. Need some description.

Comment: would it be possible to make a function with a button that runs that function then have that function take the info from a written box using .get() to write to a file

Comment: You can make a function that will run after the button press. In the function, you can use `.get()`  to accept the input from the **entry box** then store that input in a variable then use this variable to write in a text file using file operation.